# It pops up an error when I launch "npm start" What is causing this problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

Ok what is wrong here? this code was working 2 days ago what happened i cant find the problem can someone pls care to fix this or tell me whats wrong? here is the app.js code which I edited into the post...........Like the same code was working some days ago but i got error with firebase stuff so I tried to install everything again on another directory but this time didnt deploy to firebase. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0G2R.png)

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home'
import Footer from './Footer';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Checkout from './Checkout';
import Login from "./Login"
import { auth } from './firebase';
import { useStateValue } from './Stateprovider';

function App() {
  const [{basket}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  useEffect(() => {
    
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
      console.log("the user is >>>", authUser);
      if (authUser){
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: authUser
        })
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null
        })
      }
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    // BEM
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        
      <Header />
      
        <Switch>

        <Route path="/login">
          <Login/>
            <Footer />
          </Route>
          
        <Route path="/checkout">
            <Checkout />
            <Footer />
          </Route>
          
          <Route path="/">
            <Home/>
            <Footer />
          </Route>


        </Switch> 
        {/* Home */}
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please share what's inside this hook - import { useStateValue } from './Stateprovider';

Comment: import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer} from "react";


export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}

    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);



this is inside stateprovider.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is on {basket} object, you can try to change to const [basket, dispatch] = useStateValue();